# read and do pattern matching from files bigger than memory

Tags: algorithm, go, design-patterns

I have one file with patterns to match urls

file1.txt

```
*.aa.com
*.bb.com/*
....
...
```

and one file with actual urls

file2.txt

```
www.aaa.com
aa.bb.cc/ddx/eee
..
```

I would like to print a url from file2.txt if it matches a pattern in file1.txt. In file1.txt “*” is a wildcard that matches differently before and after the delimiter

a) On the hostname, before the first “/”, it matches any characters that is not “/”
b) On the pathname, after the first “/”, it matches any characters

how do i do this optimally in go by reading to buffer. The files are so large that we can't store it in memory

present solution is:
read through the file2 first and for each line in file2 compare every element in file1. and print if there is a possible match. how do we optimally do it? Could we decrease from O(N*K) where N is total elements in file1.txt and K is total elements in file2.txt

Comment: Your copy of TAoCP contains a whole section on these types of algorithms.